# app/mage.php not found in sub-sub-directory store

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore

having problem making this work. our magento store is located inside of existing php framework. `example.com/magento`.

our substore will be `example.com/magento/store1`

I already try different suggestion:

```
../app/Mage.php
/../app/Mage.php
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . /substore/app/Mage.php
and the whole path of the Mage.php
```

but still none of the list works..

**UPDATE 22/07/2015**

after removing all item except

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.2.0', '<')===true) {...}
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::run('example', 'website');
```

and don't forget to reindex, System > Index Management...

the website show but the problem is that template, css and js is not loading..
when i view the source code it shows `example/online/store1/css/style.css`
how can i fix this? thank you very much

**UPDATE 2 22/07/2015**

The solution in the problem of not `loading template, css and js can be fix in the system > config > web`.. change the base link urls..

**UPDATE 23/07/2015**

after fixing everything, i found another problem in here. the magento connect manager is not working. it only displays `The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.` please help me to fix this problem. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your store have running from sub dir.

You need to set skin,js,media url at configuration.

It should be:

- skin: `http://YourmagentoInstnaceUrl/skin/`
- media : `http://YourmagentoInstnaceUrl/media/`
- js: `http://YourmagentoInstnaceUrl/js/`

for that store.

[image]

In picture

- my magento system install at `/var/www/html/magento1911/`
- and store french has been running from

  `/var/www/html/magento1911/store1/`

Comment: still getting same error..... May i know what are all the change need to do in .htaccess file and index.php file.